# JavaCV on Android with ARMv6

Tags: android, opencv, ffmpeg, arm, javacv

I got problems getting JavaCV (http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) to run on my Samsung Galaxy S5570i device. According to this site http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_pop_plus_s5570i-4544.php this device has an ARMv6 CPU. I tried several deprecated versions of JavaCV that still include builds for ARMv5, because I had problems building it on my own. None of this versions worked on my device. I also tried running this on a virtual device which should simulate ARMv5 as long as I know. I always get exceptions that libraries couldn't be found, e.g.: "Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1312]:  1306 cannot locate '_ZNK2cv6KDTree14findOrthoRangeERKNS_11_InputArrayES3_RKNS_12_OutputArrayES6_S6_'.
I know that it is not recommended to use JavaCV on ARMv5 or ARMv6 CPUs, but I want to implement a feature in my app and provide it also for older CPUs, even if it's slower than on newer ones.
So what could be the problem? Did I use wrong versions or what versions should I use?
Hope to get an answer here.

Thanks in advance!

xoidberg

Comment: Any special reason why you chose javacv instead of android opencv?

Comment: opencv4android is pretty nice, but I need ffmpeg for video processing too and javacv provides both

Comment: Ok that is a special reason :P